# Should I manually pass use_sim_time to all nodes in a ROS 2 launchfile?

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, use-sim-time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Should I *always* manually transmit the `use_sim_time` manually to all my nodes in a launchfile in ROS 2, if I want to be able to slow down or accelerate the simulation time or be able to run it on rosbags ?

The only official example I have is from [the robot state publisher tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/URDF/Using-URDF-with-Robot-State-Publisher/#create-a-launch-file), where it is transmitted manually.

But I would expect a way to setting it globally, since it is the *entierity* of a ROS 2 system that should affected by time when you slow down or accelerate a simulation, or replay a rosbag. And because it is repetitive and add length to the code.

Is there such a way instead ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371458/should-i-manually-pass-use_sim_time-to-all-nodes-in-a-ros-2-launchfile-?/) by [deb0ch](https://answers.ros.org/users/43192/deb0ch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2021-02-09

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ottojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/70007/ottojo/) on 2021-04-23**:
Hi! Did you since find a way to set use_sim_time globally (besides setting it in the launchfile)?

**Comment by [austin](https://answers.ros.org/users/73735/austin/) on 2021-04-25**:
It would be convenient to have a global use_sim_time. However its up to each node to implement so i am not sure this is even possible or desirable.

however ever robot i have seen is has to pass it throughout the launch ecosystem because to your point it really does effect everything. I alsot breaks if every node is not on the same use_sim_time param.  So de facto there is a global use_sim_time concept.

Therefore i think this is a good feature request and would require updated to rclcpp and rclpy i think. somewhat related and definitly good place for more info on the client library implementations of ros time: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can set_parameter solve this problem?
[#q368802](https://answers.ros.org/question/368802/ros2-set-parameters-from-file-and-directly/)

---

Originally posted by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) with karma: 307 on 2021-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey ! Nice to see some movement around this question !

Since I posted, we found a neat solution that works great for us : using the `/**:`  syntax in the .yaml params file, where `**` matches the names of all the nodes :

**params/simulation.yaml**

```
---
/**:
    ros__parameters:
        use_sim_time: true
```

**launch/do_stuff.launch.py**

```
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():
    """Launch stuff using ROS 2."""
    params = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('your_package'), 'params', 'simulation.yaml')

    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='stuff',
            executable='do_stuff_node',
            name='do_stuff',
            parameters=[params],
            output='screen'),
    ])
```

---

Originally posted by [deb0ch](https://answers.ros.org/users/43192/deb0ch/) with karma: 101 on 2021-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2022-01-13**:
but how do you use this if your node has it's own parameter file?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See this [PR](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/3131) for an alternative solution. @NEngelhard

---

Originally posted by [tnajjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/36992/tnajjar/) with karma: 166 on 2022-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1